# How do I set the height value of the button I put programatically in the StackView?

Tags: swift

**I put a view and a stackView on the storyboard.**

[image: storyboard screen]

**I want to put a button in the stack view programmatically, but the button automatically takes the height value of the stackView. How can I give a height constraint to the button?**

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var stackView: UIStackView!
    var array : [UIView] = []

//I want the height of each button I throw in the StackView to be 20.
    let buttonHeight: CGFloat = 20
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
      
        setupUi()
        
        self.array.forEach { button in
            self.stackView.addArrangedSubview(button)            
        }
    }

    func setupUi() {
       self.array.append(makeButton())
    }
    
    func makeButton() -> UIButton {
            
        let button = UIButton()
        button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        button.backgroundColor = .green
        button.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: buttonHeight).isActive = true
        button.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 286).isActive = true
        return button
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

> How can I give a height value to the button

Give it a height constraint. But of course a lot depends on the constraints and configuration of the stack view itself, none of which you have shown. Indeed, in this simple situation it is far from obvious what benefit you derive from using a stack view at all. The job of a stack view is to generate constraints; if you're going to apply constraints to the button yourself, the stack view is unnecessary.

Comment: I don't understand which one should I give height constraint? I gave the button programmatically height. No matter how many buttons I put in the Stack View, I want it to be 20 high.

Comment: Did you read my answer? Without more information about how the stack view is configured and what it's for, the question is pointless.

Comment: Yes I read your answer

Comment: And yet you still have not provided the required information.

Comment: What information? If you say, I can send

Comment: Sigh. "A lot depends on the constraints and configuration of the stack view itself, none of which you have shown."

Comment: Stack view only have  four constraint like in the picture. Trailing space to equal: 40, Leading space to equal: 40, Bottom Space to Equal : 10 and Top Space Equal : 24 and also Alignment: Fill, Distribution = Fill Equally and spacing : 5

Comment: So if distribution is fill equally, then giving your arranged subviews a height constraint is illegal and such a constraint will have no effect. You are asking to stack view to subdivide its own height equally.

Comment: So what would you suggest I do? On this screen I created, there will be sometimes 1, sometimes 2 buttons. There is no problem when there are 2 buttons, and when there is only one button, the button is very large. :(

Comment: You might try Distribution of `fill`. But as I've already told you, I suggest you stop using a stack view. Instead of fighting a stack view, just make your own constraints.